# Problems with sorting by field after update in ElasticSearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch, bulkinsert

Every night I am inserting my data into elasticsearch using PHP with bulk insert. During the day when users are updating the information, I am updating every result individually, but after the update problem is appearing. The results which were updated later are not sorted evenly with the others, but are showing after this.

I have a field for "price" which has type "double". When I'm creating the array for the bulk insert, I'm specifically telling that the price type will be double:

`$result['price'] = (double) $result['price'];`

The results are going into my elastic index and everything is fine. The sorting by price works perfect. The problem is after update. I am not using the bulk update and it's one by one:

`$this->getClient()->update($params);`

Again I am parsing the field like "double" before sending it into elastic, but here is when the problem is appearing. When sorting by price, all the information which was updated later, goes after all results.

For example. My original data was:

> item1 | 10$
> item2 | 11$
> item3 | 15$
> item4 | 25$
> item5 | 30$
> item6 | 40$

After updating item1 and item4 it will be:

> item2 | 11$
> item3 | 15$
> item5 | 30$
> item6 | 40$
> item1 | 10$
> item4 | 25$

I'm thinking that elastic does something different during bulk insert and singular.